# Conda cannot set up a specific version of Python

Tags: python, conda

I am creating a conda env with `conda create -n env python==3.8`. But when I activate it and do `python -V`, it shows `Python 3.6.8`. Outside of the activated conda env `python -V` outputs `Python 3.8.13`.

I've gone through similar issues but none of the advice helps. I am desperate and mad :D

Comment: do `which python` to see the path

Comment: @TimurShtatland i've redone the same thing, doesn't help

Comment: @Chris_Rands i've put an alias for python `alias python='python3'`, so it shows `alias python='python3'  /usr/bin/python3`

Comment: Well, conda isn't going to install the env at `/usr/bin/python3`, so there's your issue... the alias is probably overwriting the correct path.

Comment: @BeRT2me but without the alias it stays at 2.7.. :D

Comment: Run `source <path to conda>/bin/activate` then `conda init` and/or `conda init zsh`

Comment: That alias is clearly interfering with your conda installation. When you `conda activate myenv`, it adds, among other things `python` on your PATH, but by default it does not add `python3`. When things are correctly installed and activated, your `$PATH` will have the conda env's bin folder earlier than `/usr/bin` and therefore (once you remove your alias) `python` will be found in your activated conda env.

Comment: @joanis well, i think you're right. but anyway, the error emerged before the alias was created. so there must be something different what causes it.

Answer (score 0):

How is your Anaconda's Version?
1.
You must use "Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda3)"  into command line,
and try "conda update --all", update your Anaconda.

2.
Did you install Python 3.6.X in your computer and update it?
If yes, this is why you at Outside see the python -V =3.6.13

Comment: I do not work locally but on HPC. By default I have python 3.8. I'll check what happens after `conda update --all`

Comment: Updating conda won't help until OP fixes their PATH and aliases.

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered the same problem, it seems that removing the alias of python works.